# USB WIFI not detecting in virtual box

Tags: wireless, 20.04, virtualbox, kali

I'm trying to connect my wifi adapter to kali linux in virtual box, but when I'm trying to add usb wifi in settings it's not being virtual box is showing no devices.
When I used same usb wifi in windows as host os and kali as guest it worked well. Now, host os-ubuntu 20.04, guest os kali.

Comment: I recall having to make changes within `virtualbox` to be able to use plugged in devices (floppy, dvd, usb etc) so I could run some *testing* within virtualbox (instead of real hardware), my guess is you haven't setup virtualbox to allow this under Ubuntu, but you did under windows. I'd compare settings where it works (windows) with where it isn't working (Ubuntu), as well as add-ons installed on host.

Comment: FYI: Kali in Debian & Ubuntu refers to a drawing program, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kali&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kali  so I don't know how the `kali` drawing program you've tagged relates to your question...

Answer (score 2):

In order to Passthrough USB Devices you need to Install the Virtualbox Guest Addons. In the Submenu where you select USB Devices you should see that at the very bottom. Then you should see Kali Linux accepting it. You can then just open a Terminal on that virtual Drive and run the autorun file and that should do it.